# How to represent group counts over a partition using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, partition

Been scratching my head on this one for a while now, so I have data that looks like this:

```
   USER  GROUP        DATE
    001     AA    02-20-21
    007     AA    02-20-21
    002     DD    02-20-21
    003     DD    02-21-21
    004     BB    02-21-21
    018     BB    02-22-21
    005     AA    02-22-21
    006     EE    02-22-21
    022     AA    02-22-21
```

And as it currently stands, I am aggregating this data as follows:

```
DATE      GROUP   USER_COUNT   NEW_USER_COUNT
02-20-21     AA            2                2
02-20-21     DD            1                1
02-21-21     DD            2                1
02-21-21     BB            1                1
02-22-21     BB            2                1
02-22-21     AA            4                2
02-22-21     EE            1                1
```

What this is doing is getting me a user count for each of the individual groups as well as a new user count from the last iteration of the group to the next.

Now this was working, however there is a critical issue. For visualization purposes I need each group represented in each date. As it stands, if a group does not appear on a date, it does not show; I need each group to appear on each date, so if we get no users on a given date, we resort to the previous user_count with no new users.

This is how I would want the above data to look:

```
DATE      GROUP   USER_COUNT   NEW_USER_COUNT
02-20-21     AA            2                2
02-20-21     DD            1                1
02-21-21     AA            2                0
02-21-21     DD            2                1
02-21-21     BB            1                1
02-22-21     AA            4                2
02-22-21     DD            2                0
02-22-21     BB            2                1
02-22-21     EE            1                1
```

Notice that after AA and DD appear, they continue to appear on every `DATE` even though they didn't grow, they use their last number.

So basically, after the first time a new group appears, it appears on every date moving forward. New groups are not fixed, new ones can appear at any time.

Here is my existing query:

```
WITH NEW_USER AS (
    SELECT USER,
        DATE,
        GROUP,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY USER
            ORDER BY DATE
        ) AS row_n
    FROM dt
),
/*Increment count of unique users based on GROUP. */
CUMULATIVE_USER_COUNT AS (
    SELECT DATE,
        GROUP,
        SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (
            PARTITION BY GROUP
            ORDER BY DATE
        ) AS USER_COUNT,
        COUNT(DISTINCT USER) AS NEW_USER_COUNT
    FROM NEW_USER
    WHERE row_n = 1
    GROUP BY DATE,
        GROUP
    ORDER BY DATE,
        GROUP
)
SELECT *
FROM CUMULATIVE_USER_COUNT
```

Also FYI the USER ID is not unique to each row, the `DISTINCT USER` is necessary.

Comment: i still don't get how you construct NEW_USER_COUNT

Comment: @nbk NEW_USER_COUNT is basically the difference of the group USER_COUNT from day to day. So when DD first appears on 2/20/21 it is one, because 1+0 = 1 (USER COUNT). Then when DD appears again on 2/21/21, we get 2 for USER_COUNT and 1 for NEW_USER_COUNT. (1 from USER_COUNT on 2/20/21 + 1 = 2 USER_COUNT on 2/21/21. Makes sense?

Comment: Please clarify your sample data - `02-20-21` is not legal DATE value in MySQL.

Comment: a further complication is that missing Dates have to be added, which makes the query even more complicated as it is, besides that i must use a ST_TO_DATE

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT `DATE`
          FROM test ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT `GROUP`
          FROM test ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT `DATE`, 
                 `GROUP`,
                 SUM(COUNT(test.USER)) OVER (PARTITION BY `GROUP` ORDER BY `DATE`) USER_COUNT,
                 COUNT(test.USER) NEW_USER_COUNT
          FROM cte1
          CROSS JOIN cte2
          LEFT JOIN test USING (`DATE`, `GROUP`)
          GROUP BY `DATE`, `GROUP` )
SELECT *
FROM cte3
WHERE USER_COUNT 
ORDER BY `DATE`, `GROUP`
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb4c55ac8897c5f5dcc84c1267f080c0

Answer (score -1):

You can generate the rows using `cross join` -- with a twist to handle the dates.  Then bring in the existing data:

```
select d.date, g.group,
       count(dt.date) as num_on_day,
       sum(count(dt.date)) over (partition by g.group order by d.date) as running_num
from (select distinct date
      from dt
     ) d join
     (select group, min(date) as min_date
      from dt
      group by group
     ) g
     on d.date >= g.min_date left join
     (select dt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group, user_id order by date) as seqnum
      from dt
     ) dt
     on dt.date = d.date and dt.group = g.group and dt.seqnum = 1
group by d.date, g.group;
```